# def form_valid for django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework. I have been using regular Django I want something similar to Django's CreateView for this model.

Intro: The superuser is the only user. All patients belong to the user and Embryos belong to the patient. One patient can have multiple embryos. Below are my models

```
class Patients(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)   


class Embryo(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patients, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    karyotype = models.CharField(max_length=100)      
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female"),    
    )
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

I am trying to make create views for my models. 
Below is what I have so far

```
class PatientsApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.PatientsSerializer
    queryset = Patients.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "phone", "email",)    

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

"""How can I get the above with Django Rest Framework. Can I do:  
     def __getattr__(self, user):
                 return self.request.user
"""
```

Below is the viewset for EmbroApiView

```
class EmbroApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.EmbryoSerializer
    queryset = Embryo.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ("code_name", "karyotype", "sex", "down_syndrome",)

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)            
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        self.object.patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=pk)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

"""How can I get the above with Django Rest Framework. Can I do:  
     def __getattr__(self, patient):
           return get_object_or_404(Patients, pk=self.patient.pk) 
"""
```

According to @Daniel Roseman solution. Have I done this correctly?

```
class PatientsApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.PatientsSerializer
    queryset = Patients.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    search_fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "phone", "email",)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


class EmbroApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.EmbryoSerializer
    queryset = Embryo.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    search_fields = ("code_name", "karyotype", "sex", "down_syndrome",)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(patient_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you mention `__getattr__` in the comment, that would have nothing to do with this.

The hooks for extra actions on create and update are called `perform_create` and `perform_update`. So as [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) show, you can do:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer)
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

etc.

Comment: will this work too `def perform create(self, serializer) serializer.save(Patients, pk=self.patient.pk)`

Comment: Er, no. What are you trying to do there? Maybe `serializer.save(patient_id=self.kwargs['pk'])`?

Comment: I tried to fix it as per your solution in the question above:- Have I done it correctly